# date picker not popping up

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I put this in the head:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, dd MM yy",
    minDate: "+2",
    maxDate: "+1Y"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
</script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

But the `datepicker` does not appear. The `textbox` appears, when i click nothing pops up. Am I doing something wrong?

it works in `jsfiddle` but just not in my `.php` page.

Comment: `id="#datepicker"` *!!* => `id="datepicker"`

Comment: ah yes i forgot that, but it still doesn't work after changing however.

Comment: Now check the snippet , if it now working on your website, try  to debugging, check the browser console log.

Comment: Console Log returns this:

style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):24 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):24)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I also got this: GET http://mydomaindotcom/resources/demos/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: It's clear what is the problem. try to check files uploaded on your server.

Comment: cant seem to find anything wrong?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, dd MM yy",
    minDate: "+2",
    maxDate: "+1Y"
  });
});
</script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: probably a variable conflict?

Comment: yes thank you i found the conflict and sorted it. it works now. Thanks :)